# Are there unicode characters for double sharp and double flat?

Tags: notation, computer

There are [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters for

- flat (U266D) ♭
- sharp (U266F) ♯
- natural (U266E) ♮

But I couldn't find characters for double flat and double sharp (at least not in the [character map program](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gucharmap) I'm using).

Are there Unicode characters for double flat<sup>1</sup> and double sharp<sup>2</sup>?

[image]

<sup>1</sup> Other than just two flat characters together; ♭♭ doesn't look quite the same as the double flat in the image.

<sup>2</sup> Ditto for double sharp; a bold "**x**" just isn't the same.

Comment: How do I actually get any of these into an answer?!

Comment: @Tim It depends on your operating system, but a quick Internet search of "how to input unicode on <operating system>" will surely help.

Comment: @Tim you google "Unicode double sharp" and copy+paste

Comment: You dont need unicode for sharps, shift plus 3 gives you a sharp.

Comment: # shift 3 is 'pound' - US, keyboard; alt/3 for UK which we'd call 'hash' - which is not the same as 'sharp' ♯

Comment: a chart with a full list of musical symbols can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_Symbols_(Unicode_block)) or here as [PDF](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

is U+1D12B

is U+1D12A

[fonts are tiny in here unfortunately]

Comment: As usual, the problem with Unicode. Doesn't show on Chrome 59, Windows 10 (not your fault, though :) Probably a link to [respective unicode info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d12a/index.htm) might help.

Comment: @AndrewT. Might be a Windows problem. The Unicode characters show on Chrome 59, Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @AndrewT. Might also be that you're missing a font with the proper characters.

Comment: Windows 10's glyph coverage is notorious, btw - MS don't include language packs by default any more, so there's a fair chance they don't in close more esoteric glyphs either.

Comment: In fact,  these comments show **exactly** why you should not depend on Unicode to transfer information to your recipients.  If you want to send oddball chars like these musical notations,  either send them via LaTeX  with instructions on the libraries required, or send them as embedded images in your file.

Comment: ..or we could all yell at MS &/or Google for not including them :p Though it works on Chrome for Mac, so that would be Microsoft that needs yelling at...

Comment: @Tetsujin I suspect Microsoft is traditionally reluctant to push full Unicode support because, due to UTF-16 being utterly engrained into all of its APIs and formerly UCS-2 being equivalent to that, many older Windows applications [fail to handle stuff correctly that isn't constant-width in UTF-16](http://utf8everywhere.org#faq.almostfw) (i.e. anything above U+FFFF).

Comment: though I barely understand that ;) The reason to support Unicode is because it's capable of working in any environment, if they can be bothered to actually be prepared for it :/

Comment: Works just fine with Firefox 58 on Mac.

Comment: fwiw, the double flat/sharp symbols are also unreadable here on Debian unstable with XFCE and Firefox, so it seems they are still not really widely provided.

Answer (score 5):

There is a fantastic site which provides all known Unicode chars and their numeric addresses.  It's well - organized and can do excellent meta-searches.

It's  [zahlee.info](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_index.html).  For double sharp,

> 119082   U+1d12a

for double flat,

> 119083 U+1d12b

That's both decimal and hex.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a terminal running `bash` you can do:

---

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> then <kbd>266d</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> = ♭
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> then <kbd>266e</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> = ♮
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> then <kbd>266f</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> = ♯

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> then <kbd>1d12a</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> = 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> then <kbd>1d12b</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> =

---

Here is a complete list of unicode musical symbols on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_Symbols_(Unicode_block)) or as [PDF](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf).

---

**Update:**

If you are on a Linux system you also have the possibility to set up a [Compose-key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key), which seems to be possible also on Windows and OSX, but you might need to install separate software. This enables you to insert the Unicode symbols via keystroke, also in your web-browser or document editor. There are several instructions how to set these up out there in the net, but since there are different approaches for all different distributions and desktops I leave it up to you to find the appropriate link.

Comment: Does one need to have a `bash` terminal in order for this to work outside of the terminal (say, in a browser)? I guess what I'm asking is: why the `bash` distinction? Or are you just saying you can also put these in a terminal?

Comment: Hey @Richard, once again thanks for the edit :-) that is actually a good question! My answer was rather meant to give an alternative for `Linux` and `OSX` users not being forced to search for the sign with a search engine in the net click a link search on the page, copy and paste it to the web browser or any document where it is needed. Instead just using `bash`. On bash you could also make an `alias` so you just type `sharp` for example and get `♯`. To assign these signs to `Compose-Keys`, there is different articles, I think on [UnixSE](https://unix.stackexchange.com)...

Comment: ...this would make them being available in the WebBrowser too.

Comment: I love when music and Linux combine :-)

Comment: Honestly saying, me too ;-)

Comment: On MacOS, it is possible to switch keyboard layout to Unicode Hex Input, then type the UTF-16 encoded chars.