# How can I type a sharp or flat In a computer file name?

Tags: notation, computer

When I name a file of a music score on the computer, I use a 'b' as flat and '#' as sharp. My question is is there in any way to use the real sharp or flat? It's not a big problem but for esthetic and the right way to name a file, why shouldn't we do it the right way . Thanks
I forgot to mention that I use windows.

Comment: And 'natural', not for your files, obviously! I tried and failed to find a simple typed sign. # nearly worked, but I can't get the Tipp-Ex off my screen...

Comment: Is it different if it's in a file name compared to just regularly entering the symbol?

Comment: See also https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/58314/are-there-unicode-characters-for-double-sharp-and-double-flat Not really a duplicate since the answer is in the question.

Comment: @Richard -- I think it depends on where you are entering the filename (and what OS you are using). On my Linux system I can use **CTRL-SHIFT-U 266d** from a terminal window to get a ♭ unicode character; works in Firefox for me too (so I can use it in posts on SE Music). But this does not seem to work for me in Dolphin File Manager for creating file names for example. Of course, OP is using Windows anyway....

Comment: @DavidBowling Oh, interesting. It seems to work just fine on my Fedora system, but that uses the Nautilus file manager. Thanks!

Comment: @Richard -- I figured that the actual file manager program might have something to do with that; I haven't used Nautilus in a while, but maybe I should break it out again ;)

Comment: There are answers that tell you how to do this, but you really *shouldn't*. It is likely to cause any number of compatibility problems, and it's better to spell out the note.

Comment: `#` might already cause problems with some programs, thinking that it's a comment and that anything coming after should be ignored.

Comment: While possible I would be extremely conservative using those characters in filenames. Better to just stick to plain old ASCII. This is because Unicode support still isn't universal and by using Unicode characters in filenames you run the risk that files can not be read by some programs. In other words: it may look nice but it is a bad idea to name your files like that.

Comment: And "double-sharp," tho' I would refuse to play a piece written in  X-double-sharp on principle :-) .

Comment: @ Pieter B -- That is a very important point that I didn't even consider. Well thought through.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a way in Windows, without installing any additional software, to be able to write those Unicode characters out of thin air using ALT + Unicode hex number.

If somebody wants to memorize those codes, he would be able to type them from thin air in a file name, a word document, notepad or other.

First as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#Hexadecimal_code_input), you need to enable `EnableHexNumpad` in your registry under the following key below.

**Way #1 to do the registry change easily**:

To do so, the easiest and fastest way is to download this .reg file and double click on it.

[Click here to download it](http://scriptsource.org/cms/scripts/render_download.php?format=file&media_id=..%2Fsites%2Fs%2Fmedia%2Fdatabase%2Fssproto%2Fentries%2Ftm%2Fhr%2Ftmhr3s5nsc_HexInputMethod.reg&filename=HexInputMethod.reg)

Double click on it:

[image]

Reboot your computer.

**Way #2 to do the registry change by hand:**

*If you're uncomfortable trying below, please use Way #1.*

First, open the registry editor by going on Start > Run (or by pressing <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) and typing `regedit`:

[image]

Then navigate to the following key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method
```

And right-click in the right-hand side box and choose New > String Value, call it `EnableHexNumpad`, and set it to `1`:

[image]

Once you're done and it looks like the image above, just close RegEdit and reboot your computer.

**Continue here**:

Now you'll be able to type the hex codes directly using ALT + your numpad. Important detail is that you should enter the Hexadecimal code of the musical character (or any other unicode character) you're trying to type.

As a quick reference, here [they are](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/List_of_useful_symbols#Music):

```
♩ 2669 quarter note
♪ 266A eighth note
♫ 266B beamed eighth notes
♬ 266C beamed sixteenth notes
♭ 266D music flat sign
♮ 266E music natural sign
♯ 266F music sharp sign
```

So now I'm going to do it for the music flat sign character. Its hexadecimal code is 266d, so I would just have to type:

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> + 266d

And once I release the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key I got:

♭

Note that you actually have to press on the numpad's <kbd>+</kbd> key after <kbd>ALT</kbd>. So it's <kbd>ALT</kbd> followed by <kbd>+</kbd> followed by the 4 number/characters.

Here I've put it in a filename:

[image]

Hope it helps somebody out there!

Comment: I'm a little bit in the back when it comes to the inside of the computer, how do I get to the registry that I can open this option?

Comment: File, Run, RegEdit.
Be EXTREMELY careful editting the registry. You can easily disable your computer by making a wrong move. You can always use the Character Map utility to find flats and sharps if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @Nachmen, I've added easy to follow screenshots on how to get there and handle it accordingly.

Comment: Very grateful for you input.

Comment: I further added another method via a double-clickable .reg file that is easier and faster.

Comment: When I went to regedit. I didn't get the enablehexnumberpad option its not there? There is only 'standard'. Please help.

Comment: @Nachmen Try using Way #1 instead

Comment: @Wadih M I Tried to download  but I get a error message, the page doesn't open.

Comment: @Nachmen, I apologize I can't assist you any further. Please follow the same steps in this answer with an IT representative so he can help you with the steps.

Answer (score 7):

♯ & ♭
 I use the system typing replacer. 
System prefs > Keyboard > Text

[image]

All my triggers start with 'nc' for historical reasons, so 'ncsharp' becomes ♯ & 'ncflat' becomes ♭.
I'm on Mac, so I've no idea about alt-codes for Windows, but if someone knows those... feel free to add.

Windows seems to handle these in file & folder names just fine - examples from Mac & Win7...

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in equivalent of a "system typing replacer" in Windows, but AutoHotkey (third-party) [does let you do that](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm).

Answer (score 6):

> When I name a file of a music score on the computer, I use a 'b' as flat and '#' as sharp. My question is is there in the ascii code a way to use the real sharp or flat?

No. There is nothing in ASCII. ASCII only has 128 characters, there's no place for musical notation in there.

Unicode, however has over 136000 (out of 1114112) assigned codepoints (as of now, more are added regularly) including 544 musical ones. The codepoints you are looking for are:

- ♯ U+266F MUSIC SHARP SIGN
- ♭ U+266D MUSIC FLAT SIGN

Comment: Minor nitpick: It's __codepoints__, not characters

Answer (score 5):

If you want ascii this site has a list of music related ascii codes:
https://www.alt-codes.net/music_note_alt_codes.php

these are mainly the ones you asked about:

```
♭   Flat note   &#9837;
♮   Natural note    &#9838;
♯   Sharp note  &#9839;
```

here are all the UNIcodes for music symbols: https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf

i was able to take this symbol: ♭ and paste into a file name on my windows machine. that may be the easiest way. good luck.

Comment: My main aim is to get the flat or sharp in the file name. I didn't know how to write the question, I thought it has to do with ascii. My aim is to get it right any way and the easiest way . Even if you gave me the code I wouldn't know how to use it. I need a step by step instructions how to do it.

Comment: are you on a windows machine or mac?

Comment: Windows 10 computer

Comment: updated answer about pasting the character into the filename.

Comment: They are *not* [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). They are [HTML character references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).