# Accepted filename character for sharp #

Tags: daw, computer

WRT **filenames**:
"b" (ascii 98) is an acceptable character for flat.
Is there an accepted character in place of the not-good-for-most-filesystems sharp "#"?

Comment: That's not actually 'sharp' [not that it really matters] but a 'US pound' or Number sign, UTF-8 23. The real sharp sign is ♯ UTF-8 E2 99 AF. I tested in macOS & Win7, both find the characters acceptable - https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8fiA.png

Comment: It's more often called "hash" (as in "hashtag"). Calling it "pound" would be a bad idea  because there is the pound sign £.

Comment: Americans call the number sign 'pound'. You have to blame them ;-) We Brits know what a pound sign looks like, it's just our transpondian cousins who get us confused ;) Its official name is "Number Sign", anything else is a preference, convenience, or attempt at distinguishing. Hash works for me, tbh.

Comment: What file system chokes on a simple # character? Even FAT could deal with that. It's simple ASCII, after all.

Comment: What filesystem(s) are you targeting?  I haven’t tried it,  but current ones should support Unicode, which, in turn, has proper flat/sharp symbols.

Comment: Its proper name is *octothorpe* - the sharp-like sign on a phone pad. The French call that sign diese, which actually means 'sharp'. The 'hash' word also comes from French - they call the letter H 'hash' - not spelled, of course!

Comment: @Tim - No, really, its proper name is "number sign" in the Unicode naming scheme. All others are 'convenience' descriptions, including *octothorpe*, which is a 'made up name' anyway, coined by Bell Labs - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign

Comment: Do I understand the question correctly that it is not possible to use # when saving a piece or  Song-file e.g. *Prelude in C#* ?

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli  the point is that some computer filesystems don't allow certain "special characters" to be in the file names.  The OP wants a naming system for his files that is accepted on any OS.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the OP wants a naming system that is not “not-good-for-most-filesystems”. But most filesystems nowadays are actually ok with pretty much all of Unicode, just not with those ASCII characters that have a special meaning!

Comment: Rather than an operating system not supporting unicode characters, I think the bigger issue would be whatever software is being used to open them. b, #, ♭, and ♯ should all be supported on standard OSes, but you can't trust software devs to always handle unicode characters.

Comment: Is anyone going to name the filesystem that can't handle ASCII "#" in filenames?  (I'm aware that a *leading* "#" can cause problems in most command-line shells, as it starts a comment, but that's not the case here.)

Comment: POSIX fully portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the German/Dutch form: for example Ces, Cis for C-flat, C-sharp respectively.   Two characters, true, but they are regular (ascii) letters.

Comment: Cis and Ces don't mean sharp and flat. Cis means C♯and  Ces means C♭.

Comment: and I believe that B is B-flat in German, and H is B-natural

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no *de facto* or official equivalent for sharp that compares to the accidental (ha!) equivalence of flat and lower case B.  But [some](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38055/utf-8-filenames) [filesystems](https://gist.github.com/doctaphred/d01d05291546186941e1b7ddc02034d3) will let you use # or even more esoteric symbols in file names.

Even so, [even in 2019](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/66368/8794), it's safer to encode the key in some kind of metadata instead of in the filename.

Comment: I think these days most OSes default to UTF-8 encoding, so none of those symbols should be any issue - except that on Windows they're a bit tricky to actually generate, needing awkward alt-codes.

Answer (score 1):

Ascii 98 is just letter 'b'.

Unicode would be the way to get a representation of the musical symbol.

Unicode U+266D is a musical flat sign.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_(music)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp_(music)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols

*Inputting* Unicode is another issue. I just cut and paste from a site that displays the Unicode symbol.

In order for a user to actually *see* the symbol, they need a font with a glyph for the character.

Using such characters in a file name is yet another issue. I'm scarred from the bad old days when various filename systems could not handle much beyond plain ascii. So I would just write out 'sharp' or 'flat' or just give up and use ascii 'b' or '#'. Neither is what we want, but plain old alphabetic ascii shouldn't fail you.